# How to import pytaxonomy==1.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hi I tried to install pytaxonomy==1.1.

```
pip install pytaxonomy==1.1
```

The installation was successful

when I tried to import,

```
import pytaxonomy
```

It says ... '

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import pytaxonomy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytaxonomy'

---

How to overcome this?

Comment: You might have multiple python installations. Try with “python -m pip install pytaxonomy==1.1“

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're installing `pytaxonamy` with same python version you're running the script with.

It's better to use `environments` in python, to prevent such errors.
[venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)